# How to combine multiple commands into single for in bash cli?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line-interface

For deleting the volumes ,first it should be taken into offline then deleted.
Below is the command to do it.

```
for i in {1..16}; do  vol --offline StressIO-v$i --force || break; done
for i in {1..16}; do  vol --delete StressIO-v$i || break; done
```

How to combine these commands and execute as single command?

Comment: That command doesn't look very sensible as it is - are you sure it is correct? If vol3 fails to go offline, it stops and doesn't set vols 4-16 offline, yet it still goes on and deletes all 16 volumes. So I have to ask myself what is the point of avoiding setting vols 4-16 offline just because vol3, which is presumably independent, didn't go offline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check exit status of first `offline` comment and execute `delete` in single loop:

```
for i in {1..16}; do
    vol --offline StressIO-v$i --force && vol --delete StressIO-v$i || break
done
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do all 16 in parallel, halting on first error, with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel --halt now,fail=1 -k --dry-run 'vol --offline StressIO-v{} --force && vol --delete StressIO-v{}' ::: {1..16}
```

**Sample Output**

```
vol --offline StressIO-v1 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v1
vol --offline StressIO-v2 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v2
vol --offline StressIO-v3 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v3
vol --offline StressIO-v4 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v4
vol --offline StressIO-v5 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v5
vol --offline StressIO-v6 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v6
vol --offline StressIO-v7 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v7
vol --offline StressIO-v8 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v8
vol --offline StressIO-v9 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v9
vol --offline StressIO-v10 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v10
vol --offline StressIO-v11 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v11
vol --offline StressIO-v12 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v12
vol --offline StressIO-v13 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v13
vol --offline StressIO-v14 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v14
vol --offline StressIO-v15 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v15
vol --offline StressIO-v16 --force && vol --delete StressIO-v16
```

If you like how that looks, remove the `--dry-run` and run it again for real.

If you are not worried about stopping on fail or the order of execution, you can simplify that right down to:

```
parallel 'vol --offline StressIO-v{} --force && vol --delete StressIO-v{}' ::: {1..16}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put && in between these two commands. This will execute both the commands in a single go.

Otherwise create a script as 
`vi example.sh`

And paste the below lines in the script files as:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..16}; do  vol --offline StressIO-v$i --force || break; done
for i in {1..16}; do  vol --delete StressIO-v$i || break; done
```

Save this file by ESC+ wq!

Then make it executable

```
chmod +x example.sh
```

Run this script as :

```
./example.sh
```